# Extract the value of self closing tag / Oracle 11g

Tags: xml, oracle

I'm facing an issue (obviously due to my lack of knowledge)

I'm starting from a XML structure like below:

```
<templatesLists>
    <templates>
        <node>value</node>
        <node>value</node>
        ...
        <taskCode taskCode="204-1"/> 
    </templates>
</templatesLists>
```

This structure is stored into a CLOB variable named v_XML_TEST. The v_RESULT variable is of VARCHAR2 type.

I can retrieve the values of any the nodes using an EXTRACTVALUE function in PL/SQL, but when it comes to the self closing  node, I cannot get anything but empty result

Here's the SQL code used:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLType(v_XML_TEST), '/templatesLists/templates/taskCode') 
INTO v_RESULT FROM DUAL;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_RESULT);
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something (I'm wondering about the path I used in the EXTRACTVALUE function ?), but couldn't find same type of question out there.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to extract the attribute value, not the node value itself. e.g. the value of `taskCode` may be as `SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLType(v_XML_TEST), '/templatesLists/templates/taskCode/@taskCode')`

Comment: Btw, you can use [`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/XMLTABLE.html#GUID-C4A32C58-33E5-4CF1-A1FE-039550D3ECFA) which is recommended by Oracle rather than deprecated function `EXTRACTVALUE`

Answer (score 0):

So, based on both your comments I tried this:

```
SELECT
x.*
FROM XMLTABLE(
    '/templatesList/templates'
    PASSING XMLType(
        '
            <templatesList>
                <templates>
                    <taskCode taskCode="204-1"/>
                </templates>
            </templatesList>
        '
    )
    COLUMNS TASK_CODE VARCHAR2(8) PATH 'taskCode/@taskCode'
) x;
```

And it worked like a charm:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxfkq.png)

So thank you very much for your help guys